# I can't figure out how to run this simple program I found on GitHub

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm

https://github.com/Valish/sherdog-api

After downloading it what I did was I first installed node.js, which I think I need in order to get everything for this (I have never used any of this stuff before at all). Then I went into command prompt and navigated to the place where the program im trying to use is. I then typed npm install and it installed all the files the program needs. I *think* that installed it correctly.

I then went into my code editor and tried to run the code through a browser. That didn't work because there is a function or something called "require" that I guess the browser doesn't have access to or anything.

Online, people seem to be saying that you run node.js programs through command prompt?

To test that I created a JavaScript file that has just this in it `console.log('Hello');`.

I then navigated to the file location and typed in command prompt "node hello.js" and it printed to the console so I know that works. What I don't know is it relevant that it works. This simple JavaScript file could have nothing to do with how the other program runs. I don't know.

Knowing that the simple file ran like this I did the same thing with the index.js file of the program I want. But when I do this nothing happens in the command prompt, it just brings up another command line. I can't figure it out.

On the GitHub site in the readme.md file for this program there is a "usage" section. However it doesn't explain how to use it as far as I can tell. It says

```
var sherdog = require('sherdog');
var url = "http://www.sherdog.com/fighter/Matt-Riddle-34072"
sherdog.getFighter(url, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
})
```

If this is how you use it I don't know what to do with this, where to input it, or anything. There is no real documentation to go with it at all. I'm stuck at this point; I don't know where to learn or what to look at.

Comment: What does the your `package.json` look like? Does it contain a `sherdog` entry?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to type the sample code into a new `.js` file. `sherdog-api` is an api, which means it will not run any code by itself. Run your new `.js` file with node.

Answer (score 0):

Node is a server running with JavaScript. It is mainly based on modules. A module just contains some code that helps you, most modules can't actually be run directly just like in your case. Instead you have to install the module, and then you can write code that works with it. At first make a new folder for your project, e.g. `myCoolServer` then open a command prompt in that folder and run:

```
npm init
```

To set up everything you need to run nodejs here, then run

```
npm install sherdog
```

To install the module. It will appear under `/node-modules/`. Now just create a new file like you did with `hello.js`, put the code into it:

```
var sherdog = require('sherdog'); 
var url = "http://www.sherdog.com/fighter/Matt-Riddle-34072";
sherdog.getFighter(url, function(data) {
   console.log(data); 
});
console.log("searching...");
```

And then run it using `node thatfile.js`, and you should see the data appearing after a while.

If you succeeded with that, you can [continue here...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: Worked perfectly, finally! Thanks!

Comment: @4el8th1ri8 glad to help :)